# Can I write a code to play the score?

Tags: sound

When I input a score image of music, can I write a code to play it?

I'd like ideas for code writing.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been projects like this. They might benefit from updating the code, especially taking in account newer versions of Wolfram Language that came out after the projects. But these projects are good starters.

- [Reading and playing sheet music](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2450505)
- [OCR for Sheet Music](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1730213)
- [Simple tablature from a Led Zeppelin song](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/machine-learning-for-images/text-recognition-to-read-music-sheets.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The "OCR" post cannot be tested because the user function is incomplete.

The "palying sheet music" post didn't even take into account the beat... Can both scale and beat be considered?

Comment: @Hoony "OCR" post has a comment pointing to GitHub with notebook. First link also looks quite good to me, maybe you can try generalizing it. It is implied on this forum that OP makes minimal effort and asks specific questions about code, especially for very general complex tasks such as this.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I'll try referring to the link you gave me.